# How to hide an album from Picasa Web?

Tags: blogger, picasa-web-albums

My Blogger account creates albums automatically in my Picasa Web to store the images I host in my blogs.

I don't want to see those albums in my Picasa Web. Is there any way to hide them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hide them from the Public Albums but you can't really hide/remove them from your account without affecting Blogger. If you will start uploading many images on Blogger then you will have to buy more storage somewhere. This somewhere is the Picasa.